# Set controller variable by calling c# webservice from angular with the use of $resource

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, angular-resource

I have a problem with using the JSON data which is comming from a service. 
The backend is written in c# and the frontend in AngularJS.

I am not able to use the object as I want in the Angular controller.

So, here is my api restful service in C#

```
[Route("v1/environment")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEnvironment()
    {
        var env = new Environment(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"]);
        return this.Ok(env);
    }
```

Then, here is my angular service:

```
module.factory('Environment', [
    '$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/MorpheusApi/v1/environment', {}, {
            getEnv: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
        });

    }
    ]);
```

Then for testing purpose I created also this service:

```
 module.factory('Env', [
    'Environment',
    function (Environment) {
        return {
            getEnv: function () {
                var s = Environment.getEnv();
                var e = angular.fromJson(s);
                return e;
            }
        };
    }
    ]);
```

Then I would use it in controller like this:

```
$scope.envLocal = Env.getEnv();
```

Then in the ui, with this

```
<p>Environment Local: {{envLocal}}</p>
    <p>Environment Local Env: {{envLocal.Env}}</p>
```

I am getting the following output, which is fine I think :)

```
Environment Local: {"Env":"testText"}

Environment Local Env: testText
```

But when I now want to let's say provide just the testText from the controller to the ui, I would do something like this:

```
    var result = Env.getEnv();
$scope.envLocal = result.Env;
```

But this is then not working.. I tried it also with angular.toJson.. angular.fromJson, but I am not getting anything then in the UI.. Why? How can I use the object properly in the controller, for example if I want to use it in an if or whatever..

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your factory like this also so you don't need to write two different services.

```
module.factory('Environment', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        var api = $resource('/MorpheusApi/:action/:subaction', {}, {
            getEnv: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                   action: "v1",
                   subaction:"environment"
                },
                isArray: false
            }
        });
        return {
            getEnv: function () {
                return api.getEnv().$promise;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

After that You just need to inject this service into the controller and you can call function easily.

```
Environment.getEnv()
                .then(function (response) {
                    //If you wants to perform any logic on response object then you can do here and after that you can assign to scope variable
                    // You can write this logic in service too
                    $scope.envLocal = response;
                });
```

You can call the service just I stated above so as $resource is returning promise your scope object will set on successfully call of api and no need to call `$scope.$apply()` here.

Suppose you have two different like

> /MorpheusApi/v1/environment
>
> /MorpheusApi/v2/environment

You can configure two routes like this call the function as per your need.

```
module.factory('Environment', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            var api = $resource('/MorpheusApi/:action/:subaction', {}, {
                getEnv: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                       action: "v1",
                       subaction:"environment"
                    },
                    isArray: false
                },
                getEnvV2: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                       action: "v2",
                       subaction:"environment"
                    },
                    isArray: false
                }
            });
            return {
                getEnv: function () {
                    return api.getEnv().$promise;
                },
                getEnvV2: function () {
                    return api.getEnvV2().$promise;
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

For more information of configration and understanding you can read this [Explanation of configration and working of $resource](https://objectpartners.com/2014/06/03/extending-angulars-resource-service-for-a-consistent-api/)

Comment: nicer way of writing the service.. will rewrite it. :)

Comment: You can configure other api also in the same service if your's routes have similar prefix path. Let me know if you want some example I will post.

Comment: sure, more examples are always welcome to understand more :) thanks

Comment: how does that behave when you are doing $querry or $post? will i then create again methods for that like getEnv and so on?

Comment: if you have different method types and api path then just configure as I shown in example . Read article you can access default methods by default with $resource on configured path.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to the fact that you're attempting to set the scope variable after calling getEnv. You may have to use an [angular promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to do that

Does something like this work?

```
var promise = Env.getEnv();
promise.then(function(res) {
    $scope.envLocal = res.Env;
}, function(err) {});
```

You might need to wrap your `$scope.envLocal` in an `$apply` also, not sure though...

```
 $scope.$apply(function () { 
    $scope.envLocal = res.Env; 
 });
```

Comment: ya, you are right,, with that it is working, forgot to say that i tried this also.. is this the only way? are there other options to do it? When i want to have it in a service, i do not want to do things like this in all controllers.. Do you have an other idea?

Comment: and the $apply would be inside the promise?

Comment: If you return a promise in a service with all the logic in the promise and return just the `Env` property, you can do something like `myService.myFunc().then(function(env){ $scope.env = env; })`

Comment: You wouldn't need the $apply if you return the promise and set the $scope variable in the return function of the promise (see above comment)

Comment: @damir All http requests are inherently asynchronous. You do not get the results of a GET request immediately. There is always going to be some lag time between the client request and the server response. Setting a variable equal to the response _before_ the server has returned it makes the variable null or undefined. You can't think synchronously in an asynchronous environment. This is why promises are used.

Comment: dan, i accept that with the promises :) this works fine, and then i can also use the object how it should be @Brett, this makes sense.. just tought that this could be solved differently.. but it is how you both say.. thanks for your help, cool that this was solved so quickly..