# Passing data from service to controller & view in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am trying to display [rest](/questions/tagged/rest)data in my view.
I have service called `"LocationService"`:

```
.factory('LocationService', function($resource, $http, $rootScope) {
  return {
    'getAvailableLocations': function() {
      $http.get('/api/v1/locations/available').success(function(response) {
        console.log(response); //logs proper response with json
        return response;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And I have some dummy controller:

```
.controller('DummyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $state, $http, $stateParams, LocationService) {
  $scope.available_locations = LocationService.getAvailableLocations();
  alert($scope.available_locations); // alerts undefined
})
```

I am sure that service gets a proper [json](/questions/tagged/json)response. However, when I am trying to display it in template (or alert from controller) I got `undefined`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: Use $resource instead of $http. $resource will take care of promises. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455067/set-controller-variable-by-calling-c-sharp-webservice-from-angular-with-the-use  how factory is configured here with $resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should look something like:

```
myApp.factory('LocationService', function($http){
    return {
        getAvailableLocations: function(){
            return $http.get('/api/v1/locations/available');
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('DummyCtrl', function($scope, LocationService){
    LocationService.getAvailableLocations().then(function(locations){
        $scope.available_locations = locations;
    });
});
```

Things that are different from your code:

1. the service now returns a promise that resolved with the location from the [json](/questions/tagged/json)response (in your code the method `getAvailableLocations` returned nothing).
2. the controller handles the promise and binds the result to the available_locations property on the scope.

Comment: @JBNizet I said that below the example ;)

Comment: But why then don't you simply use `return $http.get('/api/v1/locations/available');`?

Answer (score 2):

That's because method `getAvailableLocations()` is async. It uses `$http.get` which returns a promise.

Your solution is this:

```
'getAvailableLocations': function() {
  var promise = $http.get('/api/v1/locations/available').success(function(response) {
    console.log(response); //logs proper response with json
    return response;
  });

  return promise;
}

controller('DummyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $state, $http, $stateParams, LocationService) {

  function getLocations() {
    var promise = LocationService.getAvailableLocations();

    promise.then(function(response) {
      $scope.available_locations = response.data;
      alert($scope.available_locations);
    });
  }

  getLocations();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**LocationService**:

```
.factory('LocationService', function ($resource, $http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        'getAvailableLocations': function () {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/locations/available');
        }
    };
});
```

**DummyCtrl**:

```
.controller('DummyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $state, $http, $stateParams, LocationService) {
    LocationService.getAvailableLocations().then(function (response) {
        $scope.available_locations = response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        console.log("Error: " + response.statusText); // If you need to show error message.
    });
});
```